# Is my proof of this lemma about Taylor Expansion correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

I tried to prove the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $f,g:\mathscr U_{x_0}\to \mathbb R$ differentiable $n$ times in $x_0$. Then
>   $$f(x)-g(x)=o((x-x_0)^n)\iff f^{(k)}(x_0)=g^{(k)}(x_0),\ 0\le k\le n$$

**Proof.** (by induction)

The claim is true for $k=0$, let's suppose it is also true for $k=n$, and let's prove it for $k=n+1$:

"$(f(x)-g(x)=o((x-x_0)^{n+1})\implies f^{(n+1)}(x_0)=g^{(n+1)}(x_0))$"

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}= 0$$

Now my thought is using L'Hopital $n$ times to achieve

$$\boxed{\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}= \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)-g^{(n)}(x)-\overbrace{(f^{(n)}(x_0)-g^{(n)}(x_0))}^{= 0\text{ for induction }}}{x-x_0}=0}$$

"$(f^{(n+1)}(x_0)=g^{(n+1)}(x_0)\implies f(x)-g(x)=o((x-x_0)^{n+1}))$"

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)-g^{(n)}(x)}{x-x_0}=0$$
Applying L'Hopital the other way around (that is, going back to the primitive), I got

$$\boxed{\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)-g^{(n)}(x)}{x-x_0}=n!\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}=0}$$

I am not sure about the boxed equalities.

Comment: Since you already have a fixed  $n$ in the hypothesis, it would be better to refer to induction on $k$, for $k\leq n$.... Have you tried induction on $k$ using the Reminder Formula for a power series ?

Comment: Your approach is fine except for the fact that you apply L'Hopital $(n+1)$ times. You can only apply it $n$ times.

Comment: Also you don't need induction. L'Hospital's Rule alone gives the implication in question.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you are right, I should refer to $k$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh in fact I did apply it $n$ times but I wrote $n+1$, thank you for the correction

Comment: How about using a Remainder Formula for the power series for $h(x)=f(x)-g(x) $ up to the term of degree $k+1,,$ and Induction on $k. $  Will that work?

Comment: Although Taylor made discoveries about power series and wrote an "acccessible" text on calculus, I dislike the term "Taylor series". Isaac Newton used them extensively, after he discovered the Generalized Binomial Theorem.  In fact he said it would be a mistake to  separate calculus from power series. (We regard that as  restrictive today.)